# Adjust the position of border

Tags: html, css

I have a bottom border of a ul. There's bottom border of links inside the list items also. I want to adjust the position of the link border so that it is exactly on the ul border, so that it looks like this:

[image]

I am unable to set the border position. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
    ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green; 
}

ul li{
    float: left;   
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

ul li a.active{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;    
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/sZ8Gu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if this will be option for you, but removing `overflow` and giving height to `ul` does the job. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ8Gu/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ8Gu/6/).

The HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;    
    list-style: none;    
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green; 
}

ul li{
    float: left;   
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color:#000000;
}

ul li a.active{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;    
}
```

Apply a padding and commenting the overflow. This will create what you want.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the solution. If not, let me know for queries - @user1251698

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding-bottom:5px; from ul{} and add it into ul li a{}.

Please see the code below :

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;      
    border-bottom: 1px solid green; 
}

ul li{
    float: left;   
    margin-right: 10px;

}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li a.active{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the padding-bottom: 5; from the "ul" to the "ul li a"

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code. You just need to remove padding-bottom of ul. Please use the following css and it will give you your desired look:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green; 
}
ul li{
    float: left;   
    margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
ul li a.active{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ8Gu/9/)

I made small changes which are as follows:

- Removed `overflow: hidden`
- Replaced `float: left` with `display: inline-block`
- Added `position: relative` to `a` tags.
- Added `bottom` value in negative with respect to the `bottom-border` value of `a` tag.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ8Gu/9/)

- Remove the gap among the tags to which you are applying `display: inline-block` to avoid unnecessary spaces in the layout design.

This solution will also work if the height of the `ul` tag is unknown.